# Fetch a row which has the maximum value for a column

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following table :

```
TNO : can be duplicate
CNo : can be duplicate
```

I need to select the maximum Tno against the CNo from Table A where a.RNO=B.RNO

**Table A**

```
Tno  Rno  name   desc
100  200  adam   aadddddd
100  200  adam   aadddddd
101  201  king   aasdfdsf
```

**Table B**

```
Cno  Rno  
101  200
```

Can you guys advise the best method please.

I tried the following but not much success

Hi,

Please see the sample data as reqeusted: so the query should

```
Actual Data :

Rowum   cno     Tno     Rno  
1   24908   24047   22021
1   24909   22424   22022
1   20438   22426   22023
```

**Required Data** : it should display the maximun tno against Cno

```
Rowum   cno     Tno     Rno  
1   24908   24047   22021    
1   20438   22426   22023
```

Comment: How do _you_ think it might work? You may find you get a better quality of answer and that people are more willing to help you if you are able to demonstrate that you have [tried something for yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Also show the result of the example.

Comment: Since your tables can have duplicate TNo(s), there can be 2 Max value

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT RowNum =
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.Rno ORDER BY Tno DESC)
    , A.Tno,  A.Rno,  name,   [desc]
    FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.RNO=B.RNO
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the `desc` column in square brackets ;-)

Comment: hi, I tried ti do an oder by cno & Tno but its not supported in CTE ?

Comment: hi, i tried ur query but still getting two records for           rowid;  tno;    cno     rno                                                     1 2488 22425 20882
1 2488 22411 22005

Comment: @user362283: Edit your question and show your sample data and your desired result. Btw, you can always use `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: hi i haved added the example in question. Thanks

Comment: @user362283: That's not sample data(of both tables) but just the result of the query.